# Oracle Queries: How can I influence the order, in which WHERE-conditions are validated?

Tags: sql, oracle

my question can best be illustrated by the following example of a query in Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A, B
WHERE A.primary_key = B.foreign_key
AND B.primary_key = 'specific value'
AND A.some_expensive_attribute = '1'
```

Let's assume that `A` is not a table, but a view and that the calculation of `A.some_expensive_attribute` is expensive considering the time it takes to compute it for one single row of `A`.

In my particular application, the view `A` is huge while there are only a few rows in `B` with `B.primary_key = 'specific value'`. Thus, it takes up to 10 minutes to compute the result.

However, when I change the last line/condition to the following (completely) redundant subselect:

```
AND (
     SELECT some_expensive_attribute 
        FROM A as A2 
     where A2.primary_key = A.primary_key
    ) = '1'
```

... it only takes less than a second. I figured that implementing the redundant subselect on the `A`-row itself changes the order to check the where conditions.

My question is: Is it possible to tell Oracle "Check this condition at the end!" ?

Please note that in the actual application (a PDM-system), I can not substitute the last line like this. Thus, this workaround is no real solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `JOIN` with those conditions `JOIN B ON A.primary_key = B.foreign_key AND B.primary_key = 'specific value' AND A.some_expensive_attribute = '1'`?

Comment: Are your statistics up-to-date, and what does the execution plan show? It spunds like it doesn't recognise that B is more selective, and/or isn't using the PK index on A (or its underlying table)?

Comment: I would like to see the execution plan.

Comment: Have you actually checked the execution plan, What you're talking about is a predicate push, and it will do that if it can. In other words if it is logically equivalent and more efficient it might first filter the source table (possibly even just an index, not even the actual table) then join, rather than build the entire view result and filter afterwards. This will be evident in the query plan. Although I see you are mainly filtering on something 'post' view anyway.

Comment: And the problem having a view instead of table is that, the hints(if any required) are not propagated inside a view. I have mentioned it in my comment below.

Comment: First of all, I have to admit that the example is a simplified version of the actual problem. In the actual case, the `A.some_expensive_attribute` is also part of the `SELECT`-Clause. I noticed that this is a huge difference since it somehow changes the whole execution plan. How can I post the different execution plans? I just press F10 in the sql developer. I am very new to reading those plans.

Comment: @piotrekkr: That is not an option, since my options to influence this kind of SELECT are very limitted due to the application context. Unfortunately, it would be too extensive to explain this whole context.

Answer (score 1):

You may try a hint:

```
SELECT /*+ ordered */ A.id 
FROM B, A -- order changed
WHERE A.primary_key = B.foreign_key
AND B.primary_key = 'specific value'
AND A.some_expensive_attribute = '1'
```

It does not change the way the conditions in the where clause are computed, but it changes the way joins are done and here B precedes A. This is worth a try.

Comment: I would not depend on hints when the query selects against views. OP mentioned that A is a view and not a table. From documentation `By default, hints do not propagate inside a complex view. For example, if you specify a hint in a query that selects against a complex view, then that hint is not honored, because it is not pushed inside the view.` **Note:
If the view is a single-table, then the hint is not propagated.**

Answer (score 0):

Usually Oracle selects the best possible plan based on the cost consideration.

If the plan is not optinmal then you should gather stats on the underlying tables in query. For stats gathering you can use `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` procedure.